# Trying to Manipulate the String in R but not getting the desired results

Tags: r, vector, gsub, cpu-word

I am a beginner with R and I have a vector called "condition" and it has following values, I want to change the value of condition to number of hours left for all the records.

```
condition <- c("10 days left", "3 days left", "22 hours left", "54 hours left", "10 minutes", "9 minutes", "Listing Expired")
```

Just to verify whether my logical concept is good, I first tried my logic on one element i.e. element[2] of the vector. It worked and I got my desired result

```
b <- as.numeric(word(condition[2]),1)*24
b
# [1] 72

bc <- paste(b, gsub(".*days left.*", "hours left", condition[2]))
bc
# "72 hours left"
```

I then tried to put it in for loop to apply the same logic on every element of vector. However it just worked for 1st two values but rest iterations are completely wrong. I am getting warnings too. Please help what changes do I need to make to get my desired output?

Declaring a variable to get the 2nd element of my strings

```
var2nd <- word(condition,2)
var2nd
```

Now creating for loop to calculate hours left for every value in the vector `condition`

```
Hours_left <- for (var in condition) {
  if (var2nd == "days") {
    b = as.numeric(word(var,1))*24
    c = paste(b, gsub(".*days left.*", "hours left", var))
    print(c)
  } else if ( var2nd == "minutes") {
    d <- round(as.numeric(word(var, 1)/60, digits = 2))
    e <- as.character(paste(d, gsub(".*minutes.*", "hours left", var)))
    print(e)
    
  } else if (var2nd == "Expired") {
    print(var)
    
  } else if (var2nd == "hours") {
    print(var)
   
  }
}

[1] "240 hours left"
[1] "72 hours left"
[1] "528 22 hours left"
[1] "1296 54 hours left"
[1] "240 10 minutes"
[1] "216 9 minutes"
[1] "NA Listing Expired"
Warning messages:
1: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (var2nd == "days") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: what does `word` do

Comment: the answers below dont really answer your question, so your `if (x == y)` statements are expecting to be evaluated to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but apparently your `var2nd` is length > 1, so you are getting `if (TRUE TRUE FALSE)` or something, hence ` the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `word`, but base R can do this relatively easily with a cautious regular expression:

```r
dat <- strcapture("\\b(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\b\\s*(day|hour|minute)",
                  condition, data.frame(num=numeric(0), unit=character(0)))
dat$orig <- condition
dat
#   num   unit            orig
# 1  10    day    10 days left
# 2   3    day     3 days left
# 3  22   hour   22 hours left
# 4  54   hour   54 hours left
# 5  10 minute      10 minutes
# 6   9 minute       9 minutes
# 7  NA   <NA> Listing Expired
```

(Notice that I don't try to save the pluralizing `s` on the strings.)

Explanation of the regex:

- `\\b` is a word boundary, either the beginning of the string or some non-alpha character (break between letters and non-letters)
- `(...)` is a group, there are two groups, and in `strcapture` these are assigned to the `num=` and `unit=` portions of the third argument
- `-?` start with an optional literal minus-sign
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits; side note, this means that `-.5` does not match, the regex can be modified to allow for this, but with a bit more work ... I'm also assuming decimals may be possible, so if it is always integers then this can be simplified a bit
- `\\.?` literal decimal, optional
- `[0-9]*` zero or more digits
- `\\s*` zero or more "blank space" such as "space" and "tab"
- `(day|hour|minute)` one of the three strings: "day", "hour", or "minute"; note that since I *don't* use `\\b` (word-boundary) here, there may or may not be an `s` after the word (or anything else after it, for that matter), and we're perfectly fine with that

From here, there are a few techniques for converting the units.

1. Lookup/dictionary; in R this is a named vector, and

   ```r
   conversions <- c(day = 24, hour = 1, minute = 1/60)
   dat$num * conversions[ dat$unit ]
   #     day     day    hour    hour  minute  minute    <NA> 
   # 240.000  72.000  22.000  54.000   0.167   0.150      NA
   ```
2. Merge in the units, often more powerful with more things to join on; often easier to "maintain", since it can be in a CSV and maintained without editing R source.

   ```r
   conversions_df <- data.frame(unit = c("day", "hour", "minute"), mult = c(24, 1, 1/60))
   dat <- merge(dat, conversions_df, by = "unit", all.x = TRUE)
   dat$num * dat$mult
   # [1] 240.000  72.000  22.000  54.000   0.167   0.150      NA
   ```
3. Simple `switch`, which can be more useful than the first (lookup), since it more easily affords default values. The disadvantage is that it is not vectorized, so we need to do it ourselves (I'll use `sapply` for that):

   ```r
   sapply(dat$unit, switch, day = 24, hour = 1, minute = 1/60, 999)
   #      day      day     hour     hour   minute   minute     <NA> 
   #  24.0000  24.0000   1.0000   1.0000   0.0167   0.0167 999.0000
   ```

   (and then multiply that as in the others). 999 is here just to demonstrate a default value ... it is not useful for this application.
4. While some may default to trying nested `ifelse`, when I see 3 or things to check I tend towards either one of the techniques above or with `dplyr::case_when`:

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   dat %>%
     mutate(
       mult = case_when(
         unit == "day" ~ 24,
         unit == "hour" ~ 1,
         unit == "minute" ~ 1/60,
         TRUE ~ 9999
       ),
       timeleft = num * mult
     )
   #   num   unit            orig     mult timeleft
   # 1  10    day    10 days left 2.40e+01  240.000
   # 2   3    day     3 days left 2.40e+01   72.000
   # 3  22   hour   22 hours left 1.00e+00   22.000
   # 4  54   hour   54 hours left 1.00e+00   54.000
   # 5  10 minute      10 minutes 1.67e-02    0.167
   # 6   9 minute       9 minutes 1.67e-02    0.150
   # 7  NA   <NA> Listing Expired 1.00e+04       NA
   ```

   (Again, 9999 is used to demonstrate the potential for a default value ... I don't think it truly applies here.)

Answer (score 0):

Using lubridate and stringr from the tidyverse.

```
library("tidyverse")

condition %>% 
  str_extract("^\\d+\\s\\w+\\b") %>%
  time_length(unit="hours") %>%
  round(2) %>%
  str_c(" hours left") %>%
  replace_na("listing expired")

[1] "240 hours left"  "72 hours left"   "22 hours left"   "54 hours left"  
[5] "0.17 hours left" "0.15 hours left" "listing expired"
```